# Cache resources on Intranet server instead of CDN for faster website?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, caching

I currently have a website (AWS) with many, many images stored in a CDN (CloudFront).

Our website is accessible in a school where many users might login and access the same resources.

It makes sense to cache these resources to the school's Intranet server and for the terminal PCs to retrieve them from there rather than the CDN...?

Is this possible?  It would mean deploying a 'pack' of resources to each school to be installed/copied to their server?

Comment: Do you have any code to share?   Please refer to: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. The fact that you didn't bother to complete the 2-minute site tour looks bad.

Answer (score 2):

Many variables here. How far are the schools from closest CloudFront CDN edge router? How many requests are we talking about? How large are the files being cached?

If you determine it is worth the time/costs of setting up a proxy on-premise I would recommend Squid caching proxy (many alternatives) Squid is Linux based and battle tested. Each school would have to build out and maintain the proxy. The added benefit would be ALL appropriate requests could be cached (not just your CDN application)

http://www.squid-cache.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a caching proxy like [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/). You would set up such a proxy on a server at the school, and configure each school computer to point at the proxy. You can configure the proxy to hold onto certain types of resources for a certain amount of time. When a person visits a page, the proxy checks if it is the right kind of resource. If so, it caches it. The next person to ask for it will be served the cached version.